# Using a regular expression to validate an email to a specific domain

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, validation, email

Good morning,

I would like to create a regular expression to validate an email address.... I can do this part using the standard "email" template in the asp control.

But what I would like to do is validate that the email is from a certain domain. Could anyone advise how I can - for example - make sure that an email is formed as [anyname]@mydomain.com?

Thanks
Guy

Comment: You should use this web site for you Regex questions. Lots of great examples. [regexlib](http://regexlib.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Basically you just need to validate that input string must be ended with `@mydomain.com`, for that you can use `$` and your validation expression would something like this

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@mydomain.com$
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks - is there anyway to ignore casing? If not then I will just do a ".toLower" on the text...

Comment: as you can see in expression, I included both lower and upper case `A-Za-z` so it will take both type of casing. You can remove whatever you don't want. I have also updated the expression so make sure you are testing with latest one

Comment: That's cool thanks - but is there anyway to test both user and lower case spelling of the "@mydomain.com"?

Comment: I have got around the casing problem by forcing lower case on the input by adding onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase(); to the textbox item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@mydomain.com
```